# How to specify an array size in a template function parameter from an enum class value?

Tags: c++, arrays, enums, static, signature

In my understanding, the code below shoudn't compile, because the enum class has to be explicitely casted to an integer type:

```
enum class MyEnum : int {
    enumValue = 0,
    ... ,
    COUNT
};

template<typename EnumType>
class MyClass {
    void Bar(int someParameters[EnumType::COUNT]) { ... }
};

MyClass<MyEnum> myObject; // compilation error at template instanciation when using an enum class
```

But using such a cast, which I would have expected to be constexpr, yields a weird compilation error using Visual Studio 2015 **(EDIT: it works with g++, so it's most likely a problem from VS compiler rather than anything else)**:

```
template<typename EnumType>
class MyClass {
    void Bar(int someParameters[static_cast<int>(EnumType::COUNT)]);
};

template<typename EnumType>
void MyClass<EnumType>::Bar(int someParameters[static_cast<int>(EnumType::COUNT)]) { ... }
```

`unable to match function definition 'MyClass<EnumType>(int [])' to existing declaration 'MyClass<EnumType>(int ['function'])'`

---

**How can we solve this compilation issue without converting the enum class to a standard enum?**

Comment: `void Bar(int someParameters[some_constant])` is equivalent to `void Bar(int someParameters[])` or `void Bar(int* someParameters)` anyhow. Just drop the array bound and be done with it.

Comment: Array size is meaningless there anyway, just remove it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik just give your comment as an answer and I'll validate it :)

Comment: @AndyG that's right thanks I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You might use:

```
template<typename EnumType>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void Bar(int (&someParameters)[static_cast<int>(EnumType::COUNT)]);
};

template<typename EnumType>
void MyClass<EnumType>::Bar(int (&someParameters)[static_cast<int>(EnumType::COUNT)])
{}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abb1639a5ad05181)

or be less restrictive and taking only pointer:

```
template<typename EnumType>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void Bar(int someParameters[]);
};

template<typename EnumType>
void MyClass<EnumType>::Bar(int someParameters[])
{}
```

Comment: This code yields the error with Visual Studio 2015.